# CLion standard input while debugging

Tags: c++, clion

What I'm trying to do is basically:

`./myProgram < myData.txt`

While I'm debugging with CLion IDE. I just can't find the option to do so.

A [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596522/c-standard-input-from-file-when-debugging-from-ide) question - but product-specific to MSVS

Comment: You should have more luck asking this question in appropriate dev's [forum](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/clion?view=discussions)

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem and it seems that CLion is not handling standard inputs yet.

I got around this problem by changing the input stream before running my program.

As an example if you want to input a file stream inside your stdin you can write in your main:

```
std::ifstream in("ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE");
std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());
```

Then you can find a way to toggle this stream change when you want. Note that for files you will need to provide absolute path since the application is run from a different directory than the current one.

I hope this can help until CLion provides a real solution.

Comment: If you don't want to do it with a file, remember there is the `stringstream`s which you can use

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your input file is `myData.txt`, you can reopen/reuse the `stdin` stream using `freopen`

`freopen("myData.txt","r",stdin);`

if you want to do the same with your output:

`freopen("myOutput.txt","w",stdout);`

this will work for std::cin, printf, etc...

You can find more information about this here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/

---

By the way, there is already a feature request for this. If you are interested, you can vote here so it gets prioritized: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3153

Answer (score 8):

[As of CLion 2020.1 this feature is built in](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/whatsnew/#v20201-apr-14):

> **Input redirection**
>
> If you need to redirect input from a file to the
> stdin of your application, you can now do that. Use a new field in the
> configuration called **Redirect input from**. Enter:
>
> - A relative path (CLion will prepend with the Working directory path).
> - An absolute path (will be remapped for remote configurations).
> - Or macros (like FilePrompt).
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Still Clion don't have the feature like pycharm where we can give input in terminal while debugging the code.

But it has an option to give input through a .txt file while debugging.

[Image of debug setting window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCGty.png)

Click the setting icon in the debug console (on upper left corner) to open the setting of debugging. Then check the "Redirect input from" box and select the input file path and click "OK".

Here you go!

Now you can give input from the text file while debugging the code.

Answer (score -3):

For me, CLion creates the executable in a file called 'cmake-build-debug'. Check out my file structure in the pic.

[image: Executable File Relative To Text File]

Then, I just opened up my terminal and went to the directory containing the executable and used this command to pipe in the text file:

```
./FirstProject < ../hw1.txt
```

Comment: Yea, but this is asking about debugging. It's not the same as running the program