# IntelliJ - CLion : What should I do to use input text file?

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, clion

I want to read .txt file in my C/C++ project in CLion IDE.

I want to automate the command that I run in bash:

`./<executable_file> < input.txt`

I edited program parameter in Run/Debug configuration.

[image: picture]

But it does not works.

Comment: Redirection is part of the *shell* not something that happens automatically when running a program. Maybe you should invoke a shell instead, that runs your program with the redirection? Or modify your program to handle command-line arguments?

Comment: It appears this is not supported yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3153  You may need to pass the file name as an argument string and let your application handle opening and reading from the file

Answer (score 11):

If someone is still interested in this, at the current date, CLion has added this feature. Go Edit Configurations (top right corner toolbar, name of your project | Debug):
[image]

Now there is an option: "Redirect input from". Just click the folder and find your input file.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not officially supported as of now, you can do the following.

If your input file is input.txt, you can use freopen to set stdin file as input.txt

```
freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
```

if you want to do the same with your output:

```
freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
```

this will work for std::cin (if using c++), printf, etc...

This will help you in debugging your code in clion

Similar Question
[CLion standard input while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971803/clion-standard-input-while-debugging)

Comment: Worth to mention: don't forget to use the relative or absolute path in case you are using C/C+​+​ Single File Execution plugin otherwise the compiler will generate an error.
useful: https://programmersought.com/article/47212852083/

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution but the alternative you can do using your command line.

```
g++ -Wall -ggdb filename.cpp -o filename
```

and run it using:

```
./filename < inputFile
```

Also, I don't think JetBrain has an official answer to this type of issue for Clion yet...