# How do I pass the output of a program to my build when running from CLION?

Tags: c++, cmake, pipe, clion, tar

I want to launch a program like this:

```bash
tar -xOzf ../data/schifo.tar.gz schifo.tsv | ./myexe
```

but directly from CLion, how can I do that? I'd rather not decompress the whole file btw

In the "Edit Configuration" interface I can only read from a file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63701805/11277878 does this help? I'm not sure if this is what you mean by edit configuration interface.

Comment: No, that is how to redirect from file i.e. `./myexe < schifo.tsv`. I'd like to use piping from another program. I don't if JetBrains' IDEs even implement such functionality tbh

Answer (score 1):

Please select `Custom Executable` in `Run Configuration` settings
[image: Select Executable]
That helps to run the application, but you will get a problem with the debugging.